# I want to replace only parameters with google.com who start with http

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I have a .txt file that contain list of urls like below and I want to replace only those all parameters with google.com that start with `http`.

**Example .txt file input:**

```
https://example.com?url=https://sub.abc.com&id=1
https://example.com?url=https://sub.abc.com&id=1&res=false
https://example.com?redirect=https://sub.abc.com&name=test&verify=false&url=https//evil.com
https://example.com?id=1&refer=http://yahoo.com
```

**Output that I want in txt file:**

```
https://example.com?url=https://google.com&id=1
https://example.com?url=https://google.com&id=1&res=false
https://example.com?redirect=https://google.com&name=test&verify=false&url=https://google.com
https://example.com?id=1&refer=http://google.com
```

Note: I want to replace only parameters that starts with `http`.

Comment: Do you want this in a bash script or in Python and what did you try yourself? What's the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: I just want desired output showed above and no matter it would be in python or bash........and i have used a tool from tomnomnom that can do this stuff but only problem I faced that tool replace  all parameters with given string.........but I want to replace only those parameters value that start with http.......https://github.com/tomnomnom/qsreplace

Comment: This is not a coding writing service: you write a program or a script and in case you have problems we might help you overcome them.